# Search UITableView without Search Bar

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

How can you search a `UITableView` without using the search bar function (i.e. I want the code to search through and return the answer?) I would like to now at what `IndexRow` the result sits within the `TableView`.

I think the answer is `UISearchController`...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out:

```
   [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[ObjectsAray indexOfObject:objetc] inSection:0]
```

This will return the IndexPath of the row of an object from from an Array used to build your TableView if you have 1 section (0)...